# Better way to consume an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, coding-style

I'm calling a stored procedure with multiple results sets (always 2) and writing the results to seperate files (in pipe delimited format).   I can't split the results sets into seperate stored procs.   I'm using IDataReader and IEnumerable to keep as little in memory in the process.

Is there a cleaner way of consuming my `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` than using GetEnumerator/MoveNext/Current to get to the inner `IEnumerable<string>` to pass to File.AppendAllLines?

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        var reader = GetLines();

        using (var enumerator = reader.GetEnumerator())
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();

            File.AppendAllLines("file1.dat", enumerator.Current);
            enumerator.MoveNext();

            File.AppendAllLines("file2.dat", enumerator.Current);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetLines()
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("connectionStringKey");
        using (var command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("getdata_sp"))
        {
            var reader = db.ExecuteReader(command);
            yield return GetInnerEnumerable(reader);
            reader.NextResult();
            yield return GetInnerEnumerable(reader);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetInnerEnumerable(IDataReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            object[] rowValues = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            reader.GetValues(rowValues);
            yield return String.Join("|", rowValues);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear by naming the method GetLines() -- it returns IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>.  Should have called it GetReaders()

Answer (score 5):

Why not a `foreach` loop? That is the most basic.

Comment: I need to pass in the file names

Comment: Have a closer look at the code. He would have to write two foreachs with one of them taking all uneven counts and the other one the even counts.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would just use a foreach loop with a separate variable for tracking which file to write to, something like:

```
public void Execute()
{
    var reader = GetLines();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var inner in reader)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            File.AppendAllLines("file1.dat", inner);
        else
            File.AppendAllLines("file2.dat", inner);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know this is subjective,  but I don't see a foreach and a counter to be much cleaner/more understandable than the GetEnumerator/MoveNext/Current method.   I think I was hoping for a a "Pop"/"Next" extension method (basically an Enumerator), maybe something new from Rx.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `SelectMany()` to flatten the enumeration, since you are only interested in the values themselves.

**Edit:**

As per comment `SelectMany()` is unsuitable given the use case, so best is to use a `foreach` loop:

```
var reader = GetLines();
int index = 0;
foreach(var lines in reader)
    File.AppendAllLines(string.Format("file{0}.dat", index++%2 + 1), lines);
```

Comment: lines are going into seperate files, so I don't think I can flatten

Answer (score 2):

Maybe turn the result of `GetLines()` into an array and access it by index (since you said there will always be 2 result sets)?

```
public void Execute()
{
    IEnumerable<string>[] rows = GetLines().ToArray();

    File.AppendAllLines("file1.dat", rows[0]);
    File.AppendAllLines("file2.dat", rows[1]);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but when I ran it, it doesn't work like expected. Since NextResult is called when .ToArray() is called, when the first Enumerable (rows[0]) is iterated, we are getting the results from rows[1]

Comment: @foson: Ah, I didn't consider that (I forgot about `NextResult()` appearing between the yield returns).

Answer (score 2):

I would just change my `GetLines` method to the following

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLines()
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("connectionStringKey");
    using (var command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("getdata_sp"))
    {
        var reader = db.ExecuteReader(command);
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        {  
          foreach(var cur in GetInnerEnumerable(reader))
          {
            yield return cur;
          }
          reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Having it return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` will produce an unnecessary burden to consumers of the API.  My guess is they will all just prefer to see this as an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: This is just some internal application code, not consumed by any other code.   How would I know my first reader has ended and I should start writing results into the 2nd file?

Comment: @foson your question specifically said there were only 2

Comment: Right,  but how does the Execute method know which values from GetLines() are from the first reader to be saved in the first file and which are from the 2nd reader?

Answer (score 1):

foreach is implicitly supported by IEnumerable. So:

```
public void Execute()
{
    var reader = GetLines();

    using (var enumerator = reader.GetEnumerator())
    {
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        File.AppendAllLines("file1.dat", enumerator.Current);
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        File.AppendAllLines("file2.dat", enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
public void Execute()
{
    var reader = GetLines();

    int index = 0;

    foreach (string line in reader)
    {
        if ((index % 2) == 0)
            File.AppendAllLines("file1.dat", line);

        else
            File.AppendAllLines("file2.dat", line);

        index++;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public void Execute()
{
    var reader = GetLines();

    var evenLines = reader.Where((str, i) => i % 2 == 0);
    var oddLines = reader.Where((str, i) => i % 2 != 0);

    foreach (string line in evenLines)
        File.AppendAllLines("file1.dat", line);

    foreach (string line in oddLines)
        File.AppendAllLines("file2.dat", line);
}
```

Comment: the 2 foreach's cause the sp to be executed twice

Answer (score 0):

You can zip your results into a `Tuple<>` with your filenames like so:

```
using System.Linq;
using FileZip = System.Tuple<
    System.String,
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<
        System.String>>;

public void Execute()
{
     var files = new string[] { "file1.dat", "file2.dat" };
     var results = GetLines();

     foreach (var file in files.Zip(results, (f, r) => new FileZip(f, r)))
     {
         File.AppendAllLines(file.Item1, file.Item2);
     }
}
```

Of course, I'm pretty sure this is going to throw as soon as you return a different number of rows, but it will do what you're looking for.